# Adding UILabel to detailTextLabel of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uilabel

In my app that consist of a grouped tableView,the detailTextLabel displays dates entered through a datepicker. and i use this dates to retrieve data from webservice. What i want to do is to add UILabels to detailTextLabel of the cells so that i can access the label's text property to get the dates and send request to webservice. i tried adding label to the detailTextLabel like this

```
cell.detailTextLabel = self.fromDate //fromDate is an instance of UILabel;
```

But its showing me error...

How can i fix this

Answer (score 1):

You should set cell.detailTextLabel.text to modify it's contents, and possibly change the layout of cell.detailTextLabel, but not try to assign another UILabel to it.

You might want to add your own label as a subview, then do something along the lines of

```
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.0f,23.0f,150.0f,20.0f)];
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f];
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    lbl.text = [@"Ref.No. " stringByAppendingString:refno];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
```